# How to change background image URL dynamically from html selector in React.js?

Tags: css, reactjs

I want to change background image URL dynamically from selector which is defined in style.css.
here is the selector

```
html {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  background: url(images/bg.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

I want to change `url(images/bg.png)` to `url(images/bg2.png)` dynamically in React.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put following Vanilla Js line in `componentDidMount()` or any other function you want 
`document.querySelector('html').style.backgroundImage  = "url(images/bg2.png)";`

Comment: Using inline styles will be a much better solution than manually manipulating the DOM Elements and their attributes.

Comment: @Ajay How you're going to update dynamically in case of inline CSS

Answer (score 0):

I would stick with inline styling for this rather than manipulating the DOM Elements and their attributes.

For Reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style

So what you want can be done like this:

```css
// CSS
.something {
  ...
  background: no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  ...
}
```

```
// JSX
render() {
  const { shouldUseOtherImage } = this.props; // or this could be this.state

  let backgroundImage = require("../../bg.jpg");

  if(shouldUseOtherImage) {
    backgroundImage = require("../../bg2.jpg");
  }

  return (
    <div className="something" style={{ backgroundImage }}></div>
  ) 
}
```

Some tweaks might be needed.

Comment: Please read the question carefully, we are suppose change CSS of <html> tag itself.

Comment: I am sure it will also work but there is no point to write many lines of code if you can solve in one line. Thumbs Up to you Answer. Thank you for taking your time.

Comment: ‍♂️ Woops! Agreed. I'll keep this here anyways... Also @JamshaidAlam why not wrap the content inside a component so that you will not have to touch DOM directly